# How to understand Ternary JavaScript expression?

Tags: javascript

I'm bad with JS at now, especially with the operator "?"

And I'm trying to understand the following code.

Maybe it could be more friendly ?

So, if I don't want to use this operator, how can it be looks.

JavaScript code:

```
function(t) {
       for (var e, r = t.length, n = "", i = 0, s = 0, a = 0; i < r; )
           (s = t.charCodeAt(i)) < 128 ? (n += String.fromCharCode(s),
           i++) : s > 191 && s < 224 ? (a = t.charCodeAt(i + 1),
           n += String.fromCharCode((31 & s) << 6 | 63 & a),
           i += 2) : (a = t.charCodeAt(i + 1),

           e = t.charCodeAt(i + 2),
           n += String.fromCharCode((15 & s) << 12 | (63 & a) << 6 | 63 & e),
           i += 3);
       return n
   }
```

Comment: Step 1 is to find the developer that wrote this code and tell them to **stop**. This is why ternary-driven code gets a bad name. This has taken it way too far.

Comment: The ternary is like an `if` except that it returns a value. `x ? y : z` is roughly equivalent to `if (x) { y } else { z }` except that it evaluates to one of `y` or `z` according to `x`.

Comment: @tadman Good idea, but I don`t know him((

Comment: "Maybe it could be more friendly?" You're absolutely on the money here. This isn't code, it's some kind of riddle.

Comment: My guess is that this has been minified, I sincerely doubt that this was written by hand (I hope...)

Comment: When faced with code like this that I'm trying to understand, the first thing I'll do is space it out a lot, make the structure of the nested ternary statements clear by splitting it up onto multiple lines and indenting everything. Then add a comment that explains this is a mess and needs refactoring.

Comment: @AaronMeese I'm not sure, I thought so too at first, but this code makes heavy use of the comma operator which I'm not sure a minifier can do so confidently.

Comment: @tadman it looks like formatted minified code. I doubt the original code has single character variable names. If it does I will shake my fist at the sky.

Comment: @Andy I've seen actual people write code like this and it's utterly ridiculous, but it's just how they roll. Technical debt superstar.

Comment: Is this a UTF-8 to UTF-16 converter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an overly complicated expression involving multiple ternary operators.

I think it should be simplified.

A ternary operator behaves like an `if` but it is an expression that returns one value out of 2 options, depending on the first operand.

For example:

`operand ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse` is a ternary expression that returns `valueIfTrue` if `operand` is "truthy" and returns `valueIfFalse` if `operand` is "falsey".

You can substitute any expression in place of `valueIfTrue` and `valueIfFalse` and this way you can get really complicated expressions, sometimes unnecessarily complex.

---

As an example of making expressions complicated, let's consider: For example: `operand ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse`

If we then replace valueIfTrue with another ternary operator, e.g. `myOtherOperand ? myOtherIfTrue : myOtherIfFalse` then the original expression becomes:

`operand ? myOtherOperand ? myOtherIfTrue : myOtherIfFalse: valueIfFalse`

This is not a nice way to write it, it can be improved like this, I just put parenthesis.

`operand ? (myOtherOperand ? myOtherIfTrue : myOtherIfFalse) : valueIfFalse`

It can be improved again by formatting like this:

```
operand 
    ? myOtherOperand
         ? myOtherIfTrue // if both operand and myOtherOperand are true
         : myOtherIfFalse // if operand is true and myOtherOperand is false
    : valueIfFalse // this will be returned if operand is false
```

This shows that code formatting is essential for understanding it. But of course the first step is to have simple code. Anyways, here is how I would format the code in the question so it can be easier to understand:

```
function myFunction(t) {
    for (var e, r = t.length, n = "", i = 0, s = 0, a = 0; i < r; ) {
        (s = t.charCodeAt(i)) < 128
            ? (n += String.fromCharCode(s), i++)
            : s > 191 && s < 224
                ? (a = t.charCodeAt(i + 1), n += String.fromCharCode((31 & s) << 6 | 63 & a), i += 2)
                : (a = t.charCodeAt(i + 1),
                   e = t.charCodeAt(i + 2),
                   n += String.fromCharCode((15 & s) << 12 | (63 & a) << 6 | 63 & e),
                   i += 3); // end of ternary operators
        return n;
    }
}
```

Now it is clearer and we see statements separated by commas inside of the two ternary operators that are used. Commas are used to execute multiple things in the same expression, e.g. `(n += String.fromCharCode(s), i++)` will increase `n` and also `i`. In this case, it is better to move those outside of a ternary and into a normal `if` statement like this:

```
function myFunction(t) {
    for (var e, r = t.length, n = "", i = 0, s = 0, a = 0; i < r;) {
        const firstCheck = (s = t.charCodeAt(i)) < 128;
        const secondCheck = s > 191 && s < 224;
        if (firstCheck) {
            n += String.fromCharCode(s);
            i++;
        } else if (secondCheck) {
            // This is originally: (a = t.charCodeAt(i + 1), n += String.fromCharCode((31 & s) << 6 | 63 & a), i += 2);
            a = t.charCodeAt(i + 1);
            n += String.fromCharCode((31 & s) << 6 | 63 & a);
            i += 2;
        } else {
            // this is originally:
            // (a = t.charCodeAt(i + 1),
            //       e = t.charCodeAt(i + 2),
            //       n += String.fromCharCode((15 & s) << 12 | (63 & a) << 6 | 63 & e),
            //       i += 3);

            a = t.charCodeAt(i + 1);
            e = t.charCodeAt(i + 2);
            n += String.fromCharCode((15 & s) << 12 | (63 & a) << 6 | 63 & e);
            i += 3;
        }

        return n;
    }
}
```

So basically break it down and take it step by step to understand it, then you can change it because you understand it.

Comment: oh my, I need more practice)

Comment: Yeah, look more clear, but I think, I need time to understand this

Comment: @SonyMag Some code is just hard to understand because it is poorly designed and formatted. You will encounter a lot of examples like this as you gain experience. You're doing great, asking questions is a good way to learn!

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this is same as:

```
function(t) {
       for (var e, r = t.length, n = "", i = 0, s = 0, a = 0; i < r; )
           if((s = t.charCodeAt(i)) < 128) {
              n += String.fromCharCode(s);
              i++;
           } else if(s > 191 && s < 224) { 
              a = t.charCodeAt(i + 1);
              n += String.fromCharCode((31 & s) << 6 | 63 & a);
              i += 2;
           } else {
              a = t.charCodeAt(i + 1);
              e = t.charCodeAt(i + 2);
              n += String.fromCharCode((15 & s) << 12 | (63 & a) << 6 | 
              63 & e);
              i += 3;
           }
       return n
   }
```

Comment: oh, its look much better now, with many thx